# How to share code base between Kubernetes pods?

Tags: kubernetes

I have 2 pods inside a single deployment yaml of kubernetes

one for code base and php-fpm together

one for nginx

how to share the code base folder to nginx ?

i dont expect to see any answer that using init command to copy the folder from pod to pod

EDIT
i also try to split frontend service (nginx) and backend service (fpm and the code), but as the application itself require complex nginx rewrite rules, therefore it wont work for my case

BUT according to this repo -> https://gist.github.com/matthewpalmer/741dc7a4c418318f85f2fa8da7de2ea1

it seem not possible to do it without COPY, but copy is super slow if u hv large file base

i wanna do the similar thing as same as docker-compose volume

Comment: Have you tried pv/pvc?

Comment: actually my question is share code file between pod within the same Deployment, it is not related to any volume type, even efs, nfs

Answer (score 2):

As far as I can suggest based on the information you've given you have the following options:

a. Build a newer image of the Nginx image as your `BASE` image and copy all your source code to that image. Then reference that image in the Kubernetes `Deployment`.

OR

b. Add your source code to a `ConfigMap` and mount that in as a volume.

OR

c. Use an initContainer (Which you've already said you don't want to do).

All of these from my perspective seem wrong. I think it might be better to revisit why you're doing this and look at whether there are other options.

EDIT (More context now):

You don't need your code added to the Nginx container.

You just need to have the host resolvable. This can be achieved by adding a `Service` that points at your PHP code with the same name as you've defined in the `upstream` of the Nginx.

Look at this article: https://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/access-application-cluster/connecting-frontend-backend/#creating-the-frontend

Comment: thx for the reply, as i want the fpm and nginx split out instead of combine it together as one image, therefore, i use fpm as base to include my source code, but i also wanna nginx to load the source code folder, otherwise, it wont able to start

Comment: @user192344 Why? Are you using an upstream code block or something? Give some context I can help out a bit more.

Comment: yes using upstream for the nginx, e.g upstream fastcgi_backend {
  server !FPM_HOST!:!FPM_PORT!;
}

Comment: In that case, you don't need your code deployed. You just need to have the host resolvable. This can be achieved by adding a `Service` that points at your PHP code with the same name as you've defined in the `upstream` of the Nginx. Look at this article: https://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/access-application-cluster/connecting-frontend-backend/#creating-the-frontend

Comment: sorry i have special config for the nginx , not only upstream, but also the nginx vhost config , e.g location /pub/ {
        location ~ ^/pub/media/(downloadable|customer|import|theme_customization/.*\.xml) {
            deny all;
        }
        alias $MAGE_ROOT/pub/;
        add_header X-Frame-Options "SAMEORIGIN";
    }

Comment: @user192344 In that case, you would be better off adjusting this and making it more native to the k8s platform you're implementing it inside. `Proxy_pass` and things like that should only need to be updated. You can definitely get around this without adding your code to Nginx.

Comment: as currently im moving the magento2 into the Kubernetes, the nginx config is not that simple, or i copy the code to NGINX, and fpm is a service? becoz i dont think the fpm needed the source code? or it required?

Comment: @user192344 I think we're stepping into territory more specific about the code base. One thing I can say with confidence is splitting these components out should be the priority. Bundling them all in a pod/container will probably hurt you long term. AFAIK, if you have all your upstream available as a service, Nginx should be able to route your traffic around k8s.

Comment: thx for your help, i just try the solution that you suggest, it work for most of the simple PHP web application , but it doesnt work for magento2, it will output 404,  as the MUST requirement of the application is to have some special rewrite and routing rule in nginx conf, and which im not able to change it